# Linux Mint 19's Panel - Hide text of open programs?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, settings, panel

I know this was possible in past versions, but the latest have removed that feature.  Is it possible to hide the program name of open programs on the Cinnamon taskbar in Mint 19, while still showing the icons, like Windows 7-10?
Thanks!